# universal argument can not work in this function?

Tags: prefix-argument

I made a function in Windows Emacs like:

```elisp
(defun explorer (&optional tex)
  (interactive)
  (let* ((current-path (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
         (file-path-at-point
           (file-name-directory
             (concat current-path (if (or (ffap-file-at-point) (ffap-url-at-point))
                                (substring (ffap-url-at-point) 5))))))
  (if (equal tex t)
     (shell-command (format "\"C:/Program Files/TeXnicCenter/TeXnicCenter.exe\" %s" (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) "\.tex"))))
  (shell-command
     (format "explorer.exe %s"
        (convert-standard-filename (or file-path-at-point current-path))) t nil)))

 (bind-key "<f11>" 'explorer)
```

In my opinion, when I press `f11`, this function should open window explorer for me, and if I press `C-u f11`, it should open a LaTeX file of current directory with Texniccenter.exe, but why doesn't it work, it just open the directory?

PS: if there is some other problems of this function, can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 3):

Optional arguments don't magically get a value when you use <kbd>C-u</kbd> unless you *tell* Emacs to do that.

Have a read of <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `interactive` (see options `"p"` and `"P"` in particular), and then see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments`.

Comment: Instead of `C-h i g ...` one can also eval `(info "(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments")`.

Comment: thanks, finally i solved the problem with `current-prefix-arg`.